# What measures were taken to clear wildlife from the Shuttle Landing Facility?

Tags: space-shuttle, landing, kennedy-space-center

What was done to prevent or remove wildlife such as alligators and birds from the runway at Kennedy Space Center, so the Shuttle could land safely?

Comment: Jumping has been tried. Without known outcome, though. https://www.space.com/22772-frog-photobombs-nasa-moon-launch.html

Comment: Space Frog is hilarious, but that's launch, not landing.

Comment: While I'd imagine tile damage at the least, I suspect birds might be more a risk to the T38 chase planes than to the orbiter.  In fact astronaut Theodore Freeman was killed when a goose struck the canopy of a T38 and shards went into the engines.  I suspect the orbiter's windows are stronger and the very high angle of attack means less likelihood of a windscreen hit and a glancing collision if one does happen.  The orbiter has no airbreathing engines to ingest anything, but the T38 does and remains at substantial risk as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For birds, NASA deployed its heavy weaponry - propane cannons.

> A series of 25 liquid propane cannons, placed in strategic locations
>   along the east and west sides of the SLF runway, are controlled by air
>   traffic controllers in the tower and remotely by bird-watchers in the
>   field. These cannons, installed in September 2007, are fired randomly
>   by zone, individually or all at once. Each rotates in a 360-degree
>   pattern for the greatest effect.

SLF = Shuttle Landing Facility

More intractable avians got a personal visit. The gun was - reportedly - only used to scare them.

> Smith fires shotguns and pistols loaded with blanks to scare large
>   flocks of birds away from the runway. From time to time, he sounds a
>   special siren from his truck or uses a remote control to set off
>   cannons.

[image]

Source: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/behindscenes/clearbirds.html

For mobile speed bumps such as alligators, my memory says a walkdown was done of the runway prior to landing.   I can't find a reference for that, however, except for this rather vague statement:

> Prior to each Kennedy Shuttle landing, it is the task of a special
>   crew to clear the runway of all debris, including any alligators that
>   might be sunning themselves on the runway surface.

Source: https://www.nasa.gov/centers/kennedy/shuttleoperations/alligators/kscovrv.html

The SLF logo proudly featured a gator!

[image]

(Personal photo)

Comment: The Space Shuttle was flown between 1981 and 2011, about 30 years. But the propane cannons were used only during the last 5 years.

Comment: @Uwe Yes, all kinds of debris including bird strikes got a lot more attention after the Columbia accident. Even more elaborate measures were used for launches including a special 'avian radar'.

Comment: But the cannons were installed four years after the Columbia accident. The first launch after Columbia was in 2006.

Comment: @Uwe it may surprise you to learn that NASA does not always move quickly.

Comment: "Wow you work at NASA! What do you do??"
"Well... I clear the runway of alligators"

Comment: @SarahBailey one of my JSC co-workers had convinced his family that it was his job to clean the space toilets. I am not sure if he ever, um, "came clean".

Comment: Are they... automated/manual turrets? Which basically skeet shoot things out of the sky? Or just fired preemptively and the noise does the job to scare things away?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn just noise, lol.  Example (no idea if this was what they used) https://www.wildlifecontrolsupplies.com/animal/WCSRJM4.html

Comment: That article was not specific, so I was picturing propane-powered flamethrower turrets. I'll steal uhoh's excuse and say I've yet to have my coffee hah.